# Issues with HTTParty.post and Ruby 1.9.2

Tags: ruby, httparty

I used to have the following call working just fine on a Rails app running Ruby 1.8.7:

```
HTTParty.post("my uri", :body => "some body", :headers => { "Content-type" => "text/xml"})
```

When I run the same line on Ruby 1.9.2 I'm getting a `MultiXml::ParseError` with this message:

```
"xmlns: URI xyz is not absolute"
```

The call to my uri works just fine when I use curl, and I get back the expected response, which looks something like this:

```
<client login="foo" numsessions="1" xmlns="xyz"/>
```

Any Insight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much struggle, I gave up on HTTParty for this. I tried Patron, which worked local, but didn't on Heroku, and I finally settled on RestClient, which worked great. https://github.com/archiloque/rest-client

Answer (score 0):

That's because curl doesn't try to parse the xmlns. You could either try making sure you use the same version of httparty with 1.9.2 as you use with 1.8.7 or asking the people in charge of that uri to make the xmlns valid

Comment: The error is coming from Nokogiri. I tried to make HTTParty use a custom parser in order to skip parsing, but I don't know how to make their example work: https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty/blob/master/examples/custom_parsers.rb... I'll contact the people who gives me that URI and see if they can fix that...